# How to file transfer between android and iPhone via bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, android

Why Bluetooth of apple devices doesn't work for transferring data or files with other devices and even with apple to apple devices? Why can't the video or files be directly downloaded in device like iPhone, iPad etc. If possible how to send files to android phones via bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

It does not now.  Not one care can say whether or not it ever will since we don't work for Apple.  Speculation is prohibited by the Terms of Use of this forum.

But you can try with [Celeste app](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2013/09/celeste-2-bluetooth-file-sharing-tweak.html)